# Передача данных из одного массива в другой

Tags: массивы, java

Всем привет.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Мне надо из массива данных (массив1) прочитать 245 байт и положить в другой массив (массив2), после чего повторить операцию, пока первый массив (массив1) не закончится, если в конце массива1 останется меньше 245 байт, то прочитать остаток и положить его в массив2.

Имеется вот такой код:

```
public static void myclass123(int keySize)
{        
        byte[] data = new byte[245];
        byte[] cipher = new byte[keySize];
        DataInputStream fis = new DataInputStream(new DataInputStream("/home/admin/workspace/myproject1/Test.txt"));
        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/admin/workspace/myproject1/Data.enc"));
        int ret = 0, count = 0;
        while( (ret = fis.read(data)) > 0 ){
            fos.write (cipher = cf.doFinal(data, 0, ret));
            count += ret;
        }  
}
```

И все работает чудесно, пока `fis` у нас `DataInputStream`, но задача изменилась, и теперь вместо `DataInputStream` у меня `byte[] MyArray1`.
Теперь, когда я передаю массив в класс, например, вот так:

```
public static void myclass123(int keySize, byte[] fis)
{
        byte[] data = new byte[245];
        byte[] cipher = new byte[keySize];
        //DataInputStream fis = new DataInputStream(new DataInputStream("/home/admin/workspace/myproject1/Test.txt"));
        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/admin/workspace/myproject1/Data.enc"));
        int ret = 0, count = 0;
        while( (ret = fis.read(data)) > 0 ){
            fos.write (cipher = cf.doFinal(data, 0, ret));
            count += ret;
        } 
}
```

ему не нравится `fis.read(data)`, он говорит `Cannot invoke read(byte[]) on the array type byte[]`, предлагает заменить на `fis.lenght` и убрать (`data`), после чего конструкция работает, только пишет в `/home/admin/workspace/myproject1/Data.enc` 0 байт, 
создает пустой файл - и тишина.

Сломал голову уже, честно признаю, что еще плохо понимаю, как работают массивы и java в принципе, но учусь, прошу помочь, уважаемые специалисты. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Массив в Java — примитивный тип данных *(вероятно, даже правильнее было бы сказать «приближение к примитивному типу»?)*. Так или иначе, у него нет метода `read`. Еще важно то, что простой массив всегда имеет заявленную длину (память выделяется в момент инициализации переменной).

Прочитать блок данных можно так:

```
java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(fis, 0, 0 + data.length); // data.length == 245
```

Здесь мы копируем из массива `fis` 245 элементов начиная с 0.

`copyOfRange` в качестве 3-го аргумента ожидает не длину, а позицию, на которой следует остановиться. То есть, чтобы прочитать вторую порцию из 245 байт, нужно вот что:

```
java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(fis, 245, 245 + data.length); // data.length == 245
```

Что значит «копируем с *245* элемента по (245 + data.length = 245 + 245) = *490*-й элемент»

Организовать цикл можно как-то так:

```
int blockSize = 245;
//byte[] data = new byte[blockSize];

int pos = 0;
int rangeMax;

while (pos < fis.length)
    {
    rangeMax = Math.min(pos + blockSize, fis.length);
    byte[] data = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(fis, pos, rangeMax);

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(data));

    pos += data.length;
    }
```

Comment: Я поленился искать метод копирования части массива :)

Comment: Вообще, я бы в таком случае просто воспользовался бы [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) или `ByteBuffer` (в зависимости от того, что там хранится в тех данных).

Comment: Больше спасибо, попробую сделать так. О результатах отпишусь.

Comment: Собрал вот такую конструкцию: 

 int blockSize = 245;
      //byte[] data = new byte[blockSize];

        int pos = 0;
        int rangeMax;

        while (pos < fis.length)
          {
          rangeMax = Math.min(pos + blockSize, fis.length);
          byte[] data = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(fis, pos, rangeMax);

          fos.write (cf.doFinal(data, 0, pos));
          pos += data.length;
          }
На выходе получаю файл 512 байт размером, то бишь не весь.
Насчет ByteArrayInputStream  не совсем понятно, как я это могу применить.

Comment: А сколько порций ожидается? Каков размер массива `fis`? Пройдись отладчиком, чтобы посмотреть, сколько раз входит в цикл.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, я так спешил, что совершил пару ошибок, собрал вот такую конструкцию, и все стало работать отлично.

        int blockSize = 245;
        int pos = 0;
        int rangeMax;

        while (pos < fis.length)
          {
          rangeMax = Math.min(pos + blockSize, fis.length);
          byte[] data = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(fis, pos, rangeMax);
          fos.write (cipher = cf.doFinal(data, 0, data.length));
          pos += data.length;
          }
Также проверил chiper decrypt - все шикарно работает. Еще раз - больше Вам СПАСИБО.

Answer (score 3):

Компилятор верно ругается, во втором варианте у вас переменная fis - это массив байтов, у него нет метода read (метод read есть у потока InputStream, который закомментирован).
Я так понимаю, что вам нужно из массива fis читать по 245 байт в массив data и потом писать их в выходной поток? Если так, то принципиально код должен быть другой. И, не понятно, почему сразу не записать весь массив fis в выходной поток, зачем порцирование по 245 байт?

Comment: > И, не понятно, почему сразу не записать весь массив fis в выходной поток, зачем порцирование по 245 байт?

Шифрует он блоками, видимо.

Кстати, @mak_hash_off, следует обратить внимание на то, что `cf.doFinal` может возвращать больше 245 байт, поэтому такой способ шифрования может оказаться необратимым (в зависимости от выбранного padding).

Comment: Все верно, шифрую блоками, на счет padding знаю, использую PKCS1Padding, с ним все в порядке, и хорошо работает, запнулся, именно когда пришлось изменить поток данных на массив, случилось так, что данные перестали приходить из файла, а стали приходить с устройства, которое отправляет их как массив данных.